# How do you access view helpers or view_context from an ActionMailer preview?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-5

How do you access the view_context from ActionMailer::Preview?

```
class EventMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  def notify_user
    EventMailer.notify_user user: stripe_detail.subscription.user, 
      plan: event.data.object.lines.data[0].plan.name,
      amount: view_context.number_to_currency(event.data.object.total / 100.0, locale: :us),
      date: Time.at(event.data.object.lines.data[0].period.start).to_date
```

> undefined local variable or method `view_context' for #<EventMailerPreview:0x0000001567a448>

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#previewing-emails

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_currency

I also tried without `view_context` and I also tried `helpers.`.

Comment: I ended up just pushing the original value all the way down into the view and calling the `number_to_currency` helper there. But really, what if I had wanted to render plain text inline? How would I call that helper?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access them directly:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#using-action-mailer-helpers

What version of Rails are you on? On versions 5.0 and earlier, you may have to explicitly declare the helpers that you need:

```
class EventMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
    helper ApplicationHelper

    def notify_user
        # ...
    end
end
```

Comment: Rails 5.0.2. That didn't work. `undefined method 'helper' for EventMailerPreview:Class`. I mentioned that "I also tried without `view_context`".